# Show that $f\left( z \right) =\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ { z }^{ 3^n } }$ cannot be continued analytically

Tags: complex-analysis

*Let* $$f\left( z \right) =\sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ { z }^{ 3^n } } \quad \left| z \right| < 1$$

> Notice that the radius of convergence of the above series is $1$. Show that $f$ cannot be continued analytically past the unit disk.

---

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens as $r \to 1^-$ with  $ z = r e^{2 i \pi k / 3^m}$ ? then say those points are dense in $\{|z| = 1\}$

Comment: Thanks,but how to show  those points are dense in $\{|z| = 1\}$.

Comment: what points ? $  \ $ :D

Comment: $z = r e^{2 i \pi k / 3^m}$

Comment: at $z = e^{2 i \pi k / 3^m}$ , $f(z)$ is not holomorphic

Comment: $z = r e^{2 i \pi k / 3^m}$, it is obvious that $ \left| f\left( z \right)  \right| \rightarrow \infty $ as $r\rightarrow { 1 }^{ - }\quad $.

Comment: yes, and for any $|z_0| = 1$, there is a point $e^{2  i \pi k / 3^m}$ arbitary close where $f(z)$ is not holomorphic / analytic, hence  $f(z)$ is not holomorphic at $z_0$